# Selenium WebDriverException: Reached error page

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, python-3.6, django-1.8

I am following a Django TDD tutorial at:
http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/taskbuster-working-environment-and-start-django-project
I get the following error when running *'all_users.py'* before and after I start the development server *'python manage.py runserver'*:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "functional_tests/all_users.py", line 15, in test_it_worked
>      self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
>    File "/Users/samgao/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 264, in get
>      self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
>    File "/Users/samgao/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
>      self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>    File "/Users/samgao/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
>      raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: >about:neterror?e=connectionFailure&u=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/&c=UTF->8&f=regular&d=Firefox%20can%E2%80%99t%20establish%20a%20connection%20to%20the%20s>erver%20at%20localhost%3A8000.

Basically the connection to localhost cannot be established.
The settings and configurations are identical to the tutorial in the previous link.

I have been struggling with the issue for two days, and would thank you most kindly if you could provide any help.

Answer (score 9):

I got the same error and what solved for me was changing from *localhost* to *127.0.0.1*:

- **old**: `self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')`
- **better**: `self.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')`

Comment: This worked for me. I had the virtualenv activated, django server running, but still got the error. Firefox starts up, tries to access `http://localhost:8000`, and fails, so selenium raises an exception. But when I refresh the browser manually, the page loads. If I change the code to do `self.browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000')`, as you suggest, the page loads first time, no exception is thrown and the test passes. Weird. I wonder if the same happens with Chrome instead of Firefox?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, the final solution is: re-install again [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

1. Unzip the geckodriver.zip
2. Move the file to `/usr/bin` directory `sudo mv geckodriver /usr/bin`
3. Goto /usr/bin directory cd /usr/bin,then you would need to run something like `sudo chmod a+x geckodriver` to mark it executable.

Answer (score 3):

this might not be your situation, but I got the same error message when running a test (same book, hehe) without having anything actually listening on the targeted port (8000, in my case). Make sure there's something listening for a request by manually opening your browser and going to localhost:8000. In my case - silly me - I didn't have the server up at all =)

Answer (score 3):

I also followed the same tutorial and came across the same error. I noticed that I am not running the django server. The following is what helped.

```
python manage.py runserver
python functional_test.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem in this situation: the application put the computer name to the proxy host,so the proxy like this:

```
theComputerName:proxyPort
```

but the theComputerName:proxyPort can not be visit,so I put this into the host:

```
127.0.0.1 theComputerName
```

then restart the application,the problem resolved perfect

Answer (score 0):

Being that this is a snapshot (around Django 1.8's time) of "Obey The Testing Goat" - perhaps the instructions there are no longer relevant. I suggest [going straight to the goat's mouth](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com) and starting over!

The issue could be related to virtualenvwrapper (which is no longer necessary) or it could be related to the port/address that you were trying to access. Depending on your version of Selenium and Firefox [there may be issues related to that as well](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/676).

Comment: btw https://obeythetestinggoat.com/ doesn't work for me, it needs www: https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation.

Based on mine, after I changed the target URL, I can get the browser to load the URL normally, which means the original URL is not available.

Another way to check:

```
import requests
html = request.get(url)
```

Print the HTML, if you get the 503, which means the website is reachable.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is probably a common search result for those working through Obey the Testing Goat, I wanted to share the solution that worked for me. I had written `self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')` and needed to use `http` instead of `https` to resolve the error.

Answer (score -1):

I learning TDD tutorial too. My problem was that inputed uncorrect url 
http://http://mysite insted of http://mysite

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).